# Is it possible to implement an asynchronous HTTP server in Rust?

Tags: http, asynchronous, rust

Is it possible to implement an async HTTP server with Rust in NodeJS async style:

```
server.on('/url, function(req, resp){
    // call resp.end() if you need
});
```

I also need to be able to implement hanging GET, i.e. when I call `resp.end` not immediately, but later, on some other event. I tried http-rotor but it panics if the request is not finalized.

Comment: Funny, but I need some real-life approach...

Comment: My point is that you seem to either be asking for someone to write code for you (which seems overly broad), or to tell you about an existing library (which is off-topic as shown on the [help/on-topic]). Your question doesn't seem to indicate why one of the existing Rust server libraries doesn't meet your needs — why must it be asynchronous? Why is a threaded server inappropriate?

Comment: Hyper has an asynchronous server as of 0.9.4 too.

Comment: You probably just want to use Iron (or other Rust http server library): https://github.com/iron/iron . See the README.md example.